# Why am I getting an error when requiring a file in my plugin?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I am developing a plugin and when trying to require a file, I get thrown the error: `Warning: require(): http:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_include=0` .

One of requires work, but the other one is throwing the error for some reason:

```
// This one works
require plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'includes/class-wp-portfolio-pro.php';


//This one throws an error
require plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . "includes/wp-portfolio-pro-cpt.php";
```

I am not sure why the bottom one throws the error but the top works just fine. In the file that throws the error, I am registering a custom post type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the names suggest, `plugin_dir_path()` will get the filesystem path, while `plugin_dir_url` gets the URL.

A file path looks something like this `/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/` and can be used by PHP to find a file on the server.

A URL will look like `https://www.example.com/wp-contents/plugins/my-plugin/` and is intended to be accessed over the web. If you attempt to require a file in PHP using a URL the server will need to request that file over the web, which is far *far* slower, and a security risk. This is why the ability to even do this is disabled by default in many setups. The error you're seeing is telling you that this is disabled.

File paths should be used for accessing files on the server, while URLs should be used to find assets from the browser.